# FusedLocationProviderClient constructor is marked as internal

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

I just updated my Google dependencies to 12.0.1 and now I'm getting this error where I'm using FusedLocationProviderClient.

[image]

Any idea why is this happening? Looking into source code, I can see the the constructors are now hidden:

```
@Hide
public FusedLocationProviderClient(@NonNull Context var1) {
    super(var1, LocationServices.API, (ApiOptions)null, new zzg());
}

@Hide
public FusedLocationProviderClient(@NonNull Activity var1) {
    super(var1, LocationServices.API, (ApiOptions)null, new zzg());
}
```

But it doesn't make sense. Why? Google obviously wanted people to migrate to this new Location Provider. Why would they suddenly make it unavailable? I've checked out the docs and I can't find anything about this.

Luckily the code still compiles and location works. But still...why?

Answer (score 5):

The documentation could have been clearer, but it seems the intention is for you to call `LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient()`. See the API [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices.html#getFusedLocationProviderClient(android.app.Activity)).

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to [version 15.0.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#april_12_2018_-_version_1500) released on the 12th it will clear the warning for you. I don't see anything in release notes or bug reports mentioning this, so it is probably just a bug introduced in `12.0.1`.